# Server won't send email to specific address

Tags: email, postfix

I set up a new RHEL 8 server and it won't let me send email to a specific address.

If I do:

```
mail -s "Testing" helpdesk@yln.info < /dev/null
```

it fails and the logs show

```
Dec  8 07:59:46 yln sendmail[2029791]: 2B8ExkYP2029791: from=administrator, size=220, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202212081459.2B8ExkYP2029791@yln.info>, relay=administrator@localhost
Dec  8 07:59:46 yln postfix/smtpd[2029792]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec  8 07:59:46 yln postfix/smtpd[2029792]: discarding EHLO keywords: CHUNKING
Dec  8 07:59:46 yln sendmail[2029791]: STARTTLS=client, relay=[127.0.0.1], version=TLSv1.3, verify=FAIL, cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits=256/256
Dec  8 07:59:46 yln postfix/smtpd[2029792]: discarding EHLO keywords: CHUNKING
Dec  8 07:59:46 yln postfix/smtpd[2029792]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 550 5.1.1 <help@yln.info>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; from=<administrator@yln.info> to=<helpdesk@yln.info> proto=ESMTP helo=<yln.info>
Dec  8 07:59:46 yln sendmail[2029791]: 2B8ExkYP2029791: to=helpdesk@yln.info, ctladdr=administrator (1000/1000), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30220, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Dec  8 07:59:46 yln postfix/smtpd[2029792]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 data=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=6/8
```

If I send to our test address

```
mail -s "Testing" helpdesktest@yln.info < /dev/null
```

it works just fine.

This is an address that's been in use for years so the problem would appear to be on the sending server. I've searched the web but I can't find anything to help solve the problem. (I would note that I have a test server which is almost a clone of the production server with the problem and sending to the email address on it works fine.)

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: "_<help@yln.info>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table_" seems pretty clear to me. You don't have "help@yln.info" in the local list of users

Comment: @roaima, I don't understand. I should be able to send email to any user in the world. What table is it that the user has to be in?

Comment: "Recipient" means "person receiving the message". The server handling messages to yln.info doesn't know who/what help@yln.info is. That's your server. You need to address this.

Comment: It's a Google Workspace server that certainly knows that address. Emails get sent to it constantly. And if I do the same mail command on the test server (which is on the same network as the problem server) the email is sent fine. I don't know how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: I don't think it is a Google Workspace server. Look at the delivery route: it's being delivered to "localhost", i.e. the same machine that's sending it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfix thinks that the domain is local and is not trying to go out and query the record for it and send it to Google's Mail Servers.

Open Postfix's `main.cf` config file and look for the following line:

```
mydestination = $mydomain, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
```

Remove $mydomain and restart postfix

```
service postfix restart
```

And try sending the mail again. Postfix will not look localy for that domain

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem. So the test server has the leading $mydomain and works fine whereas the production server has to have that removed. That's bizarre.

Comment: @Chanel in that case the definition for `$mydomain` is different on the two machines

Comment: Where is $mydomain set?